# tomcat start but can't listen from another pc

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, redhat

I am running tomcat in linux pc whose ip address is 192.168.1.31 and port number is 8084 . I have tested it via the following url :

http://192.168.1.31:8084/

The welcome message is come as depicted int he following picture :
[image]

But when I enter the above address from another pc (windwos 10 ) , I am getting this error :

```
This site can’t be reached

192.168.1.31 took too long to respond.
Search Google for 201 8084
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

I have firewall off . I cant understand where is the error . Please help me .

Comment: To be clear, from the "other PC", do you still include the port# in "the above address"?  If not, that should be present in the URL the same way as the test.

Comment: Yes . I have entered address http://192.168.1.31:8084/

Comment: Just to confirm the obvious, you're in the same network, right? What's the ip address of the windows pc?

Comment: In addition to the below answer, you can look here about the "private address" vs "public address"
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IP address which starts with`192.168.` by default is for local network, so if your windows machine isn't in this network it actually can't reach your tomcat. Check `ipconfig` on your windows machine and try to find address which starts from `192.168.` to find it out.

Also you can change your tomcat bind address in the config file `tomcat/conf/server.xml` and bind tomcat to public IP address.

Another solution is to configure your *iptables* to forward traffic from some port of your public IP to the port `8084` on your local network.